# Desktop shows a combination of gnome 2 and gnome 3 elements

Tags: gnome, 12.10

I have upgraded to ubuntu 12.10 from ubuntu 12.04.

I had gnome shell installed in ubuntu 12.04.  After the upgrade, my Desktop appears to be a mix of gnome 2 and gnome 3 elements. Have attached the screenshot.

[image]

What should I do?

By the way the version of my gnome shell is 3.6.1

Here's the .xsession-error file generated on my machine after login.

> > openConnection: connect: No such file or directory cannot connect to brltty at :0 X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request
> >     code or no such operation)   Major opcode of failed request:  138
> >     (ATIFGLEXTENSION)   Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()   Serial
> >     number of failed request:  15   Current serial number in output
> >     stream:  15 gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code
> >     256 gnome-session[3355]: WARNING: Session 'gnome' runnable check
> >     failed: Child process exited with code 1
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get
>   edid: unable to get EDID for output Window manager warning: Cannot
>   bind "switch-panels" to Control_L: it needs a modifier such as Ctrl or
>   Alt.
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): color-plugin-WARNING **: unable to get
>   EDID for xrandr-LVDS: unable to get EDID for output
>
> (gnome-panel:3455): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion `accelerator != NULL'
>   failed
>
> ** (gnome-panel:3455): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'
>
> mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST pointer
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST pointer
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST pointer
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST pointer
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST pointer
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2
>   keyboard
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical
>   Mouse
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST
>   keyboard
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST
>   pointer
>
> (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean:
>   assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)'
>   failed mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device SynPS/2 Synaptics
>   TouchPad mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device AT Translated Set 2
>   keyboard mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Logitech USB Optical
>   Mouse mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device UVC Camera (05ca:183e)
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Power Button
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Video Bus
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Sony Vaio Keys
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST keyboard
>   mouse-plugin-Message: checking on device Virtual core XTEST pointer
>
> (gnome-panel:3455): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion `accelerator != NULL'
>   failed
>
> ** (gnome-panel:3455): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'
>
> ** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
>   ** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
>
> ** (gnome-settings-daemon:3439): CRITICAL **: setup_bg: assertion `manager->priv->bg == NULL' failed
>
> (gnome-panel:3455): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.0/./gobject/gsignal.c:2459: signal
>   `size_request' is invalid for instance`0x8e5ac50'
>   ** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed:
>   'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open
>   usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or
>   directory Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Answer (score 2):

According to the screenshot, you are running GNOME Fallback (in Ubuntu it is known also as GNOME Classic) instead of GNOME Shell.

Next time you log in, select 'GNOME' instead of 'GNOME Classic'.  If still fails, it is because there is an issue with 3D in your driver.  When it is not possible to run 3D, GNOME switches to GNOME Fallback.  You can also check ~/.xsession-errors for more clues.

Comment: i have selected gnome on my login screen. Pls check the question now. Have added the xsession-errors

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ATI graphics card? If so, try switching to the open-source driver instead of the proprietary driver (Software Sources >> Additional Drivers >> "Using X.Org X server" >> Apply >> Restart Computer).

The graphics driver you have probably isn't compatible with the version of Xorg that comes with Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: i don't have anything listed under the additional drivers section.

Comment: can you pls guide me.. i don't have anything listed under the additional drivers section